# Example Amazon S3 Get Bucket Request using Access Key and Secret

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I am struggling to understand the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) on how to make a request to Amazon S3 API's to retrieve a list of Objects.

The documentation doesn't show how to Authorise the request using just the `access key` and `secret`. Can someone post an example? preferably something I can use in Postman to test with.

Comment: Is there a reason *not* to use one of the many AWS SDKs?  They hide all of the signature stuff for you.  But if you must, take a look at the [Authenticating Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) docs for more details.  It is a pain to do by hand and there is no way to give you an example that will work for you without your credentials.

Comment: Because there isn't one available for the language I am using so I need to understand how it works using a vanilla HTTP Request so I can build it myself.

Comment: If the docs are insufficient here then note that the AWS SDKs are open source so it may be helpful to review the source code for sigv4 signing and emulate that in your language of choice.

Answer (score 1):

AWS supports two signature versions: Signature Version 4 and Signature Version 2. 
You should use Signature Version 4. All AWS services support Signature Version 4, except Amazon SimpleDB which requires Signature Version 2. 
All AWS regions support Signature Version 4.

Here is a great article by ŁUKASZ ADAMCZAK explaining how to generate and sign the S3 request using openssl and curl:

[Amazon S3 REST API with curl](http://czak.pl/2015/09/15/s3-rest-api-with-curl.html)

Comment: Note that this is the Signature Version 2 algorithm, only supported in regions where S3 was a available before 2014.  Newer regions require Signature V4, which also works in older regions.

Comment: You are right. Removed the misleading instructions and updated to point to the V4 article.

Answer (score 0):

The real challenge will be to do the sigv4 signing. I truly urge you to use one of the established SDKs (what language are you using??).  If not wrap a call to the AWS CLI.

If you really want to implement it yourself the I urge you to open source your efforts so others can benefit.

I would start by setting up the bucket with no auth (so anyone can read from it) and determine how to make a request to S3 first. You can see some raw HTTP Request examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#RESTObjectGET-responses-examples

Then you'll be on to the fun part, sigv4 signing the request. This is a well documented process but still a good amount of effort. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html